# Как ограничить число выбираемых файлов в диалоговом окне jQuery-File-Upload?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как ограничить число выбираемых файлов в диалоговом окне jQuery-File-Upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак, как и размер, браузеры не предоставляют такой возможности.

Comment: Зато можно отказаться от всех файлов, кроме первого, и если большой файл, то тоже выбросить.

Comment: Средствами JS?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, да, через file api, которое blueimp fileuploader использует.